# String to array

Tags: c#

I have a string :

```
id0:xxxxx:id0-value:xxxxx:id1:xxxxxxxx:id1-value:xxxxx:id3:xxxxxxxx:id3-value:xxx
```

I just need the value for idX-value from the string into array.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Tried anything or totally clueless?

Comment: Good place for some Regex!  One word... Match Collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way, the value is in position (4x - 1):

```
var list = input.Split(':');
var outputs = new List<string>();

for (int index = 0; index < list.Count(); index++)
{
     if (index % 4 == 3)
         outputs.Add(list.ElementAt(index));
}
```

Comment: The string can be dynamic, more then 3 values.

Comment: it can be id0:xxxxx:id0-value:xxxxx:id1:xxxxxxxx:id1-value:xxxxx:id3:xxxxxxxx:id3-value:xxx 
, or id0:xxxxx:id0-value:xxxxx:id1:xxxxxxxx:id1-value:xxxxx:id3:xxxxxxxx:id3-value:xxx:id4:xxxxxxxx:id4-value:xxx

Answer (score 2):

Use String.Split()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx

```
String myString = "id0:xxxxx:id0-value:xxxxx:id1:xxxxxxxx:id1-value:xxxxx:id3:xxxxxxxx:id3-value:xxx";
String[] tokens = myString.Split(new Char[] {':'});
```

The token array will contain {"id0","xxxxx","id0-value","xxxxx","id1","xxxxxxxx","id1-value","xxxxx","id3","xxxxxxxx","d3-value","xxx"}

The second possibility is to use String.IndexOf() and String.Substring().

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs

Int start = 0;
ArrayList tokens;
while((start = myString.IndexOf("-value:", start)) > -1) {
  ArrayList.Add(myString.Substring(start+6, myString.IndexOf(":", start+7);
  start += 6; // Jump past what we just found.
}

Answer (score 1):

Split it using a Regex(a regex which splits : coming after x), then split using colon `:` and use first index as a Dictionary Key and Second index as Dictionary value.

Comment: The reason I wouldn't recommend RegEx is because the data appears to be in a set pattern. RegEx compilation and usage is expensive both in terms of CPU and memory in comparison to just splitting the string. If the data is not in a clear pattern, then RegEx is the way to go.